# Netsuite - Get the current form ID from a script

Tags: netsuite

I have a couple of customized sales order forms, and I would like to be able to determine, from within a script, which form the user is currently using.

For example, let's say I have a form called "Regular Sales Order" (internal ID 100) and another form called "Special Sales Order" (internal ID 101). They're essentially identical, with some small differences. The Special order form is for zero-charge orders, such as for POCs or for test licenses. All other orders would use the Regular form.

Our sales orders all have a "custom price" option, so all prices can be overridden. I want to add some validation to ensure that no line item in a sales order has a 0.00 charge, but only if the form in use is the Regular Sales Order form. Conversely, if the Special form is in use, then all line items should have a 0.00 charge.

How can I detect the current form ID from a script, so that I can tell whether the user is using the Regular or the Special form? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

try **customform** field

```
nlapiGetFieldValue('customform');
obj.getFieldValue('customform');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example snippet from a userEvent script:

```
function BeforeSubmit() {
    currentForm = nlapiGetFieldValue('customform');
    if (currentForm == 100) {
        // code for form with internal ID = 100
    }
    else if (currentForm == 101) {
        // code for form with internal ID = 101
    }
}
```